# Convert date formats for storage

Tags: java, android, sql

All of my code formats and displays dates as this:

```
   3-1-2011
   3-15-2011
   12-1-2011
   12-15-2011
```

What's the best way to format that as YYYY-MM-DD for storage in an sqlite db?

Comment: So what are these dates before they are displayed? Are they `Date` objects?

Comment: This is like your previous question, in SQLlite dates are stored as text. You need to write a routine to convert the text format to YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: @NullUserException -- they are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   String inputDate =  "12-15-2011";
   DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
   Date date = df.parse(inputDate);
```

Comment: I'm trying that but it wants me to change DateFormat to SimpleDateFormat and instead of Date date, String date. But when I do that I get an exception. Unknown pattern character - 'Y'

Comment: I have changed the format method to parse and it should work.